# how to run git inside a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian

I have the following compose file and I need to run multiple commands on the container.  I need the container to do a git pull to grab the containers config.  This is a Debian build so I have tried to install git and then run the git command.  When I do this, the container constantly restarts.

```
---
version: "3"
services:
  kamailio:
    image:  kamailio/kamailio:5.2.8-stretch
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: kamailio
    #environment:
    command:
       - bash
       - -c
       - >
       apt-get install git -y;
       cd /tmp;
       git clone https://github.com/dOpensource/dsiprouter.git;
    volumes:
      - kamailio_Data:/etc/kamailio
```

Comment: In your case the container is started and run the command and then kill itself.. it does not have a reason to stay on or long running process to keep it running. Normally you have a server running in an container, which keeps it up. Also you have a restart policy which is spinning up a new container as the old one stops.

Comment: My goal is to start the container and run the git command to download the config.  I don't want to change the restart behavior, my goal is to get the container not to restart rather download the config and stay on, just not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: It might work better to run `git clone` on your host, outside of Docker; modify the configuration as necessary; and use `volumes:` to inject the config file into the container.

Comment: What do you mean by Stay on? Docker does not stay on unless it have a long running command. what is the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` of your base docker image ?